# @Field(type=FieldType.keyword) being ignored on certain properties on ES

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I used spring boot `2.2.4-RELEAS` with elasticsearc `6.8.6` and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch `3.2.4`.

When i created my Document

```
    @Id 
    private String transactionId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Float)
    private BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("0");

    @Field(type = FieldType.Float)
    private BigDecimal fees = new BigDecimal("0");

    @Field(type = FieldType.Float) // final amount given to the user
    private BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("0");
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Float)
    private BigDecimal priceinEuro = new BigDecimal("0");

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String currency;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date garaTransactionDate;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date providerTransactionDate;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    private Boolean isCashIn = false;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String action;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String status;
    
    //game or ebook
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String type;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
    private Long contentId;  //ebook or apk id
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String provider;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String appUserId;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String countryCode;

}
```

I don't know why `status` is not defined as keyword in elastic search. Even in the mapping, it is recognized as text

```
  "appusertransaction" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "action" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "amount" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "appUserId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "contentId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "countryCode" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "currency" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "fees" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "garaTransactionDate" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "isCashIn" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "priceinEuro" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "provider" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "providerTransactionDate" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "status" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "total" : {
          "type" : "float"
        },
        "transactionId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong ? Even currency, provider are also mapped just as Text.

Thanks.

Comment: actually, your ES mapping looks like you have deleted index when application was running and ES created new mapping based on incoming data.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, i just try and even when the cluster is not receiving data, i got bad mapping.

Comment: The versions you provide don't make sense. Please provide a minimal compilable and runnable project that reproduces this error.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch sorry, it was a mistaka. I corrected it. I don't really know why i have this situation. The version of elastic is 7.10 hosted on aws. I saw the code to some dev from Capgemini, and don't understand why for some reasons keyword are not correctly created. That's why in the other thread, i'm trying to update my spring and elastic. Please why only two fields are not working ?